# Unspent Output Consolidation UX. Any wallets that have built-in consolidation feature?

Tags: wallet, consolidation

Consolidation is important however sometimes nerve racking because you are sending your entire amount, if you accidentally send to the wrong address somehow this can be detrimental to anyone's Bitcoin user experience. Do any reputable Bitcoin wallets automate consolidation to avoid this failure?
I believe this would significantly improve UX for average end users.

Comment: Some wallets will detect that you're sending to yourself and will make this clear in the UI, for example by showing no money (except for fees) actually leaving the wallet.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad do you know which wallets offhand?